# GoogleAppEngineLauncher: database disk image is malformed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sqlite

I've written a small application for Google App Engine and each time I want to run my app I have the following error:

```
*** Running dev_appserver with the following flags:
    --skip_sdk_update_check=yes --port=13080 --admin_port=8005 --clear_datastore=yes
Python command: /usr/bin/python2.7
INFO     2014-11-22 07:47:57,008 devappserver2.py:745] Skipping SDK update check.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 83, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 79, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 997, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 990, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 789, in start
    request_data, storage_path, options, configuration)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 888, in _create_api_server
    default_gcs_bucket_name=options.default_gcs_bucket_name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 403, in setup_stubs
    logservice_stub.LogServiceStub(logs_path=logs_path))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/logservice/logservice_stub.py", line 107, in __init__
    self._conn.execute(_REQUEST_LOG_CREATE)
sqlite3.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed
```

When I run an other application I've created, I don't have any error. 
I tried some basic ideas:

- delete/re-add the app
- remove the app launcher and reinstall it
- reboot the mac
- locate where the database could be with some grep

Nothing worked. Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

The default log database filename is `log.db`. It is stored in your app storage directory, which by default is located in your `tempfile.gettempdir()` directory, named `appengine.[appname].[userid]`.

The `appname` portion takes the value from your `app.yaml` (look for the `application` entry), replaces `:` colons with underscores, and removes everything before the last `~` tilde (if there is any).

So if your app is called `foobar` and your username is `jbj`, the corrupted SQLite database is located in:

```
`python -c 'import tempfile;print tempfile.gettempdir()'`/appengine.foobar.jbj/log.db
```

On Mac OS X, `tempfile.gettempdir()` returns a hashed path under `/var/folders` somewhere; it is simply taken from the `TMPDIR` environment variable, so you *should* just be able to use:

```
rm $TMPDIR/appengine.foobar.jbj/log.db
```

You can safely delete this file, it'll be re-created the next time you start the app.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I had to restart the app from Google Launcher SDK :). Thank you for the info, was very helpful :)