# Google App Engine Development Server DatabaseError('database disk image is malformed',)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to run my Google App Engine App with the local Development Server
I'm getting this error: DatabaseError('database disk image is malformed',)

I think the database files are corrupt. 
I followed this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075350/googleappenginelauncher-database-disk-image-is-malformed). I tried removing the temporary files at `/mytemporarydir/appengine.myproject.myuser` but I'm still having the problem.

I also tried run the server with option `--storage_path=...`. It could run (with empty datastore) but I needed sudo access and the database is not saved when I stop the server (the process is blocked).

I want to run dev server as always, without Database Error, with default storage_path and without sudo

Which file could be corrupt so I delete it?

EDIT: I also tried running the server with --clear_datastore option.
I'm using Mac OSX

> INFO     2017-06-16 17:35:01,122 recording.py:676] Saved; key:
>   **appstats**:001100, part: 40 bytes, full: 1682 bytes, overhead: 0.000 + 0.006; link: http://localhost:8080/_ah/stats/details?time=1497634501114 ERROR
>   2017-06-16 17:35:01,130 api_server.py:374] Exception while handling
>   service_name: "logservice" method: "Flush" request:
>   "\n\255\001\022\252\001\010\357\261\305\243\363\302\324\002\020\001\032\234\001Saved;
>   key: **appstats**:001100, part: 40 bytes, full: 1682 bytes, overhead:
>   0.000 + 0.006; link: http://localhost:8080/_ah/stats/details?time=1497634501114"
>   request_id: "OVEehjkdIK"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 349, in _handle_POST
  api_response = _execute_request(request).Encode() 
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 225, in _execute_request
  make_request()
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 220, in make_request
  request_id)
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub.py", line 129, in MakeSyncCall
  method(request, response, request_id)
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/logservice/logservice_stub.py", line 203, in _Dynamic_Flush
  self._insert_app_logs(request_id, group.log_line_list())
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub.py", line 166, in WrappedMethod
  return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/logservice/logservice_stub.py", line 214, in _insert_app_logs
  '(?, ?, ?, ?)', new_app_logs) 
DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed

RuntimeError("DatabaseError('database disk image is malformed',)",) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
  req.respond()
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
  self.server.gateway(self).respond()
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
  response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 287, in __call__
  return app(environ, start_response)
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/request_rewriter.py", line 314, in _rewriter_middleware
  response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 159, in __call__ INFO     2017-06-16 17:35:01,137 module.py:809] default: "GET /admin/4785074604081152 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
  self._flush_logs(response.get('logs', []))
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 297, in _flush_logs
  apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('logservice', 'Flush', request, response)
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 95, in MakeSyncCall
  return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 329, in MakeSyncCall
  rpc.CheckSuccess()
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 157, in _WaitImpl
  self.request, self.response)
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 206, in MakeSyncCall
  self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
File "/Users/arcano/Virtualenvs/muncommdsenv/muncommds/parts/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 269, in _MakeRealSyncCall
  raise pickle.loads(response_pb.exception()) 
RuntimeError: DatabaseError('database disk image is malformed',)
```

Comment: Did you try the `--clear_datastore` `dev_appserver.py` option?

Comment: on linux I find the default datastore location in `/tmp/appengine.<appname>.<username>`

Comment: @DanCornilescu thanks. Yes, that's the first thing I tried. And I'm using mac osx

Comment: was this resolved?