# Error in Google App Engine - Log Service - SQLite

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using Google App Engine on Ubuntu within Linux Subsystem for Windows.

When I start `dev_appserver.py` I receive errors with the following line resulting in this, which I am understanding to be a corrupted sqlite data file.

> File "/../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/logservice/logservice_stub.py", line 181, in start_request
>           host, start_time, method, resource, http_version, module))
>       DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed

Based upon this post I am understanding there is a log.db referenced.
[GoogleAppEngineLauncher: database disk image is malformed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075350/googleappenginelauncher-database-disk-image-is-malformed/27075713)

However, when I run the script referenced, the resultant path does not contain a log.db leading me to believe this is a different issue.

Any help in identifying the appropriate database, for the purposes of removing, would be appreciated.

*Per comment added --clear_datastore=1 and did not notice a change*

dev_appserver.py --host 127.0.0.1 --port 8080 --admin_port 8082 --storage_path=temp/storage --skip_sdk_update_check true *--clear_datastore=1* main/app.yaml main/sync.yaml

Comment: Try running the server with `--clear_datastore` option

Comment: No luck. I'm wondering if this is a repeat of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595344/google-app-engine-development-server-databaseerrordatabase-disk-image-is-malfo Any idea where the actual db files are stored?

Comment: I added a print statement to logservice_stub.py and the file affected was identified as temp/storage/logs.db. Removing it solved the error.

Comment: You should add an answer for it to not leave the question unanswered

Comment: will do. thanks, was wanting to dig why --clear_datastore didn't resolve it.